# Error with tablefootnote in newest version (1.1a) of package

Tags: errors, footnotes

With the newest version of the package [tablefootnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) (version 1.1a), something is broken when using `\tablefootnote` within a `table` environment, something I discovered when a paper I am writing refused to compile after updating packages. What can I do to circumvent this problem (until the packages is fixed?)? Below a MWE and the error thrown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        A & B\tablefootnote{C}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> ! Too many }'s. \tfn@footnotetext ...{tfn:\theHfootnote }{}}\fi }
>                                                     {\relax }\thinspace #2}}{... l.8 \end{table}

Comment: The error doesn't show up if `hyperref` is loaded.

Comment: When I run this in writelatex.com it compiles perfectly. Weird. See https://www.writelatex.com/664629xbvbhd#/1402342/

Comment: @azetina writelatex.com is usually far behind (it uses TeX Live 2011, IIRC), so it's not surprising.

Comment: The problem is in a gigantic mess of different types of conditionals, around line 261, in the definition of `\tfn@footnotetext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was fixed in version 1.1b, which was just uploaded to the CTAN team. Please allow a little time for processing and spreading to the mirrors. The problem was the `\ifHy@hyperfootnotes` construct (well, several of this) inside another `\if`, and LaTeX got confused which `\fi` and which bracket belonged to which `\if`. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for reporting the bug!

(To circumvent the problem before the new version is installed on your system, please additionally load the `hyperref` package. For a printed document this should not change too much.)